Use automodule twice on the same module
I have a module in a Python package that I'm documenting with Sphinx. Lets say it has the two functions module.function_a and module.function_b (there are more function and classes in my actual case). I want to structure the docs and use automodule twice, that is, I have one rst file containing
.. automodule:: module
    :members:
    :exclude-members: function_b

and a second rst file containing
.. automodule:: module
    :members:
    :exclude-members: function_a

Everything works as I want it, but I get a warning:

WARNING: duplicate object description of module, other instance in rst_file_1, use :no-index: for one of them.

Is there a way to avoid the warning without using :no-index:? Or a different way to split the documentation of a single module into multiple pages using automodule?
